# com.browserstack.local.LocalException: Error trying to download BrowserStackLocal binary

Tags: selenium, jenkins, browserstack

While trying to execute a Selenium test on BrowserStack through Jenkins, with the capability 'browserstack.local' as 'true' I am getting the following exception-

```
com.browserstack.local.LocalException: Error trying to download BrowserStackLocal binary
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is returned due to the plugin not being able to download the BrowserStackLocal binary.

This may be due to the presence of a proxy.

Try to add the proxy flag in Jenkins for the plugin. Something like:

[image: flags]

If there is authentication on the Proxy, additional flags will be needed for specifying the username and password of the proxy.

Refer to https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/automate#test-websites-environments-behind-proxies

Also, you need to ensure that traffic to `*.browserstack.com` is whitelisted on the proxy on ports `80` and `443`.